# How do I write a function with variable classes in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following bit of code in multiple places in my app:

```cs
var subReport = new XRptEventHeader();
var eventHeaderList = FreqReports.GetEventHeaderList(studyPK);
var dataSourceSubReport = (XRSubreport)oRpt.FindControl("xrSubreportSite", false);
dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource = subReport;
dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource.DataSource = eventHeaderList;
```

It is used in multiple places where the type for `oRpt` differs. I tried to use a generic something like this

```cs
public static T SetEventHeader<T>(T oRpt , Guid studyPK)
{
    var subReport = new XRptEventHeader();
    var eventHeaderList = FreqReports.GetEventHeaderList(studyPK);
    var dataSourceSubReport = (XtraReport)oRpt.FindControl("xrSubreportSite", false);
    dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource = subReport;
    dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource.DataSource = eventHeaderList;
    return oRpt;
}
```

But when I get to the line

```cs
var dataSourceSubReport = (XtraReport)oRpt.FindControl("xrSubreportSite", false);
```

and `oRpt` it doesn't have the `FindControl` function even when I cast with the base class of each class.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could get this to work?

Comment: Each type of "report" would need to implement `FindControl` with the same parameters. Best way to do that is to define an interface and then implement it in each of your report types or implement as a base class. Then you type the parameter as the interface or base class and it works.

Comment: `T SetEventHeader<T>(T oRpt , Guid studyPK) where T:XtraReport`?

Comment: Imagine you call the method with `int` as your `T` here, of course that doesn't have a `FindControl` method.

Comment: Also, `oRpt` seems to always be the same type here, do you really need to use generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to RB as they gave me the information I needed.
It also made me realize I needed to cast something else and try/catch for if the section didn't exist for some reason. Here is the final code that worked:

```
public static T SetEventHeader<T>(T oRpt, Guid studyPK)
        where T : XtraReport
    {
          
        try
        {
            XRSubreport dataSourceSubReport = oRpt.FindControl("xrSubreportSite", false) as XRSubreport;
            var subReport = new XRptEventHeader();
            var eventHeaderList = FreqReports.GetEventHeaderList(studyPK);
            dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource = subReport;
            dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource.DataSource = eventHeaderList;
            return oRpt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return oRpt; //subsection not present
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is restrict the value of `T` to a base class or interface that all your `oRpt`s share. You do this by adding a "generic constraint".

In your case I suspect you are writing a website, and so the base class of all your `oRpt`s can be [System.Web.UI.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol). If you are not, then work out an appropriate base type (class or interface) for your particular needs.

```
public static T SetEventHeader<T>(T oRpt , Guid studyPK)
     // Add a "generic constraint" to ensure T is a Control.
     where T : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    var subReport = new XRptEventHeader();
    var eventHeaderList = FreqReports.GetEventHeaderList(studyPK);
    var dataSourceSubReport = (XtraReport)oRpt.FindControl("xrSubreportSite", false);
    dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource = subReport;
    dataSourceSubReport.ReportSource.DataSource = eventHeaderList;
    return oRpt;
}
```